# Octave: imagesc of matrix with more that 9999 rows does not work

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have to use Windows 7 (64bit) and precompiled Octave 3.2.4 (32bit, latest Octave for Windows that seems to work for me). I want to plot large images/matrices:

```
%image = ones(10000,500); % does not work
image = ones(9999,500); % does work
imagesc(image);
print('test.jpg', '-djpeg');
```

The smaller matrix does work. If I use the large matrix, Octave does not plot the whole matrix and crashes.

Do you have an idea how to make Octave plot images with about 12000x500 pixels?

Comment: Both work here (octave 3.8.2 on linux). 3.2.4 is really outdated. Have you tried the newer versions listed [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows) ?

Comment: Yes, current version 3.8.2 does work under Windows. In other 3.8.[0,1] version the installation (compilation) of packages did not work. Maybe that's the way to go...

Comment: As huntj said I am going to update to a newer Octave version.